# What is the meaning of Ringo's words when speaking to Virgil Earp?

Tags: dialogue, tombstone

In Tombstone, drunken Ringo says these words to Virgil Earp:

> Ringo: **Sister boy should've stuck around**.
>
> Virgil Earp: What do you want, Ringo?

What is the meaning of these words when it is said to Virgil Earp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ringo was not addressing Virgil specifically, but the Earps in general. They had just spoken with Deputy Billy Breakenridge (Jason Priestley), who in the movie is portrayed to be a little effeminate, and perhaps in a relationship with Mr. Fabian (Billy Zane), thus "sister boy". Ringo was out for revenge and says Billy should have stuck around as a sort of threat to the Earps for what he might do without the lawman around.